# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Check the code bellow. In my chorome extension code i am getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` when i try to read cookie. Whats wrong i am doing here?

content.js:

```
chrome.cookies.get({ url: 'http://example.com', name: 'somename' },
    function (cookie) {
      if (cookie) {
        console.log(cookie.value);
      }
      else {
        console.log('Can\'t get cookie! Check the name!');
      }
  });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "AutoMailSystem",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.test.com/"
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "cookies"
      ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["<all_urls>"],
            "js":["jq.js","Content.js"]
            
        }
    ]
    

}
```

Comment: I think you should do it in the background and send the result to content.

Comment: [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) cannot access the `chrome.cookies` API directly.